# What tense is this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses

*The room is filled with a lot of junks.*

What kind of tense is this?

Comment: Do you mean junk, as in worthless trash, rather than "junks?"

Comment: @jmrpink Yes, "this room is filled with a lot of junks" means that the room is filled with many [oriental vessels](https://www.hong-kong-traveller.com/hong-kong-junk.html) (or more likely scale models of them)

Comment: Good point: it could be filed with old Chinese sailing ships!

Answer (score 1):

This is present tense of the verb [**to be**](https://www.bing.com/search?q=to%20be%20conjugate&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR) .

> The room **is** filled with [full of] a lot of junk [*note: singular*].

---

Past tense:

> The room **was filled** with a lot of junk.

Less ambiguous present tense:

> The room **is full** of a lot of junk.

Answer (score 1):

It is the present tense (**is**) used with the past participle for the [passive voice](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/passive-voice/).

> The passive voice is used to show interest in the person or object that experiences an action rather than the person or object that performs the action. In other words, the most important thing or person becomes the subject of the sentence.
>
> Example: The passive voice **is used** frequently.
>
> Sometimes we use the passive voice because we don't know or do not want to express who performed the action.

That last sentence seems to described your example. We don't know (or don't care) *who* filled the room, just that it is (now) filled.

p.s. "junk" is uncountable so it should be "filled with junk" not "junks"

Comment: passive is a voice, expressing the relationship between the doer and doee of a verb. tense refers to temporality. [https://www.bing.com/search?q=grammatical+voice&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR]

Comment: @tidbertum Thanks for that extra clarification. A more specific link (from your search) seems to have a good overview of "voice" for those not familiar with the concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)